# Is there a way to maintain the order of dictionary values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, collections, tuples, ordereddictionary

Below is my code to find distinct site and distinct names from a list of tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict,OrderedDict
weblogs = [
     ('Nanda', 'google.com'), ('Maha', 'google.com'), 
     ('Fei', 'python.org'), ('Maha', 'google.com'), 
     ('Fei', 'python.org'), ('Nanda', 'python.org'), 
     ('Fei', 'dzone.com'), ('Nanda', 'google.com'), 
     ('Maha', 'google.com'), ]
web = [t for t in (set(tuple(i) for i in weblogs))]
res = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in web:
    res[j].append(i)

a = OrderedDict()
a = dict(res)
for i,j in sorted(a.items()):
    print(i,j)
```

The output of this keeps changing between the below two outputs:

```
dzone.com ['Fei']
google.com ['Maha', 'Nanda']
python.org ['Nanda', 'Fei']

dzone.com ['Fei']
google.com ['Nanda', 'Maha']
python.org ['Fei', 'Nanda']
```

Is there a way to maintain a constant order of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the order of the values in the set. A simple solution would be to change that line:

```
web = [t for t in (set(tuple(i) for i in weblogs))]
```

like this:

```
web = [t for t in (sorted(set(tuple(i) for i in weblogs)))]
```